# Export data from MySQL to XML with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, export

I have a MySQL database on my website, and I would like to know how I could get an XML output via PHP of the following columns in the table: I know that there are many Questions about that topic, but I can't find a solution that solves my problem.

This is what I have right now:

```
 $xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('bev');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $xml->startElement("bev");

  $xml->writeAttribute('id', $row['id']);
  $xml->writeRaw($row['name1']);



  $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml->flush();
```

And this is what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <bev id="0000000000">
        <name1>Water</name1>
        <name2>without gas</name2>
        ...
    </bev>
    <bev id="0000000010">
        <name1>Water </name1>
        <name2>with gas</name2>
        ...

    </bev>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: *I can't find a solution that solves my problem*...what's the problem? Other than missing root (which you may have left out in post but looks to be in code) that looks like an XML to me.

Comment: It does generate an xml, you are right, but whats the code to generate the elements in between the "bev". Hope you know what I mean.